# how to bind objects to gridview

Tags: asp.net

i am calling an webservice where my webservice is returing an object( which contains data like

```
empid  name
1      kiran
2      mannu
3      tom
```

WebApplication1.DBLayer.Employee objEMP = ab.GetJobInfo();
now my  objEMP  has this collection of data

```
empid  name
1      kiran
2      mannu
3      tom
```

how can i convert this object into( datatable or LIst) and bind to gridview

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post what the returned object looks like?  Is it a list or something or...? I'm speaking C# code, not example data :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method in your DAL needs to return something like a `List<WebApplication1.DBLayer.Employee>`. This will then fulfil the the requirement that DataSource must implement IEnumerable.

Your code would looks something like this

```
List<Employee> employees = ab.GetAllEmployees();
gridView1.DataSource = employees;
gridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
gridview.DataSource = objEMP;
gridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: its giving an error if i bind like this  Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.

Comment: Check your service... It should return a list or an array. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: its returning a class type called objEMp   webservice

Answer (score 0):

It is better to create a Generic Collection like

```
List<Employee> emp =  ab.GetJobInfo();
Gridview1.DataSource = emp;
GridView1.DataBind();
```